# Kafka Streams: Login module control flag not specified in JAAS config

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, jaas

I am trying to run my Kafka Streams app using Java and passing my Confluent credentials as Environment variables in the form of K,V pair.

But I am facing an issue with error as -

```
- org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Login module control flag not specified in JAAS config
```

Here is how I am setting my Kafka Properties -

```
Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
kafkaProps.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "MyKafkaApplicationV1.0.0");
kafkaProps.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "tmp/state-store");
kafkaProps.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, System.getenv("bootstarpServers"));
kafkaProps.put(StreamsConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, System.getenv("securityProtocol"));

kafkaProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, System.getenv(SASL_JAAS_CONFIG));
kafkaProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, System.getenv(SASL_MECHANISM));
```

Here is how I am passing the environment variables -

```
export saslJaasConfig=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='MyUserName' password='MyPassword';
export saslMechanism=PLAIN
```

But if I hardcode the Creds string directly in the properties object like -
`kafkaProps.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='MyUserName' password='MyPassword';");` then it's working and showing no error.

Kindly help on what am I missing!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `export` doesn't "pass" anything. Plus, you shouldn't put plaintext passwords in your terminal history. How are you running the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the jass config as jvm argument.Please try this.

-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas_config.conf

contents of jaas_config.conf

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="username"
    password="password";
 };
```